# Changing a page's title in a Bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a beginner in HTML/CSS and was using this [Bootstrap theme](https://www.themezy.com/demos/65-miniport-responsive-website-template) for making my personal website. As you can see, the nav bar has **Top**, **Work**, **Portfolio** and **Contact**. I want to rename **Top** as **About**. For that, I replaced Top by About wherever necessary in *index.html* but the result isn't what I desire. The website gets messed up with the **About** being an inactive link. Should I change the CSS files and do the replacement there as well?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so all you need to do is change `<article class="container" id="top">` to `<article class="container" id="about">`

And change `<a href="#top">Top</a>` to `<a href="#about">About</a>`.

Now if there is CSS associated with `#top` you will need to change that to `#about`. That is all you should need to do.

Comment: I did make the changes but they are not getting reflected. 
index.html still shows **Top** instead of **About**.

Comment: Can you do a codepen or share your code or something? That doesn't really make sense why it wouldn't be changing after making those changes.